# Почему не устанавливается kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pip

Подскажите как установить kivy/

```
$ python3 -m pip install kivy
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/my_kivy_project/build/kivy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

```
cat /home/user/.pip/pip.log
 Removing temporary dir /tmp/my_kivy_project/build...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/my_kivy_project/build/kivy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 715, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/my_kivy_project/build/kivy
```

```
$ pip install --upgrade setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Судя по последней ошибке, похоже, что у вас Python 3.4, а pip установлен для более новой версии (как минимум для Python 3.6, т.к. f-строки появились начиная с этой версии).

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Ну это в общем-то ничего не добавляет. Ошибка указывает на f-строку, f-строки появились только в Python 3.6, судя по тексту ошибки - запускается с помощью Python 3.4. Нужно или обновиться до Python 3.6 (поставить отдельно), либо откатить pip до стандартного, и не обновлять.

Comment: Какая у вас операционная система? Попробуйте pip удалить, потом установить заново.

Answer (score 0):

если вы используете IDE вы можете его установить через нее или вот последовательность трех команд после которых kivy будет установлено:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv

python -m virtualenv kivy_venv


python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples
```

в последней вместо [base] можно написать [full] если хотите установить все принадлежности kivy, а не только основные.

ну и по хорошему прочитать документацию.
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip

Comment: $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/tmp/my_kivy_project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")

Comment: если у вас линукс тогда иногда нужно писять python3 а не просто пайтон. Иначе без понятия у меня и на виртуальной машине все работает и на винде

Comment: python3 либо просто питон, ничего не меняет. Ошибка одна и таже.